# Custom name when upload file in laravel

Tags: file-upload, filenames, laravel-9

I wanna ask, how am I supposed to write on the `$fileName` if I want to custom an image file when I upload it like for example `product-code_product-name.jpg` or something like `111_instant-noodle.jpg`?

and this is the code:

```
$fileName = <something to code here>;
$path = $request->file('the_file')->storeAs('the_path', $fileName, 'public');
return $path;
```

or maybe any other way for me to achieve that?

what I want to achieve is when the file is uploaded to the database, I want the file saved with this kind of name "product-code_product-name.jpg" and not use its original name.

I tried:

```
$fileName = time() . $request->file('the_file')->getClientOriginalName();
```

but it saved with its original name, and I dont want that, so what am I supposed to do?

thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to create custom file name according to your choice/requirement.

```
// Combine the sanitized product code and product name
$customFileName = $productCode . "_" . $productName . ".jpg";

// Replace any spaces with underscores
$customFileName = str_replace(" ", "_", $customFileName);

// Save the file with the custom filename
$path = $request->file('the_file')->storeAs('the_path', $customFileName, 'public');
```

Comment: ah ok i, ill try it.. ill let you know if its really working. thank you

Comment: its really working as i want, thank you so much once again

Comment: Welcome, that was easy stuff : )